# htaccess ограничить пользователей с динамичным ip

Tags: .htaccess

Добрый день.
 Недавно прочитал на каком-то сайте, что можно при помощи файла .htaccess ограничить доступ к сайту пользователей с определенных ip.
и как бороться с динамичным ip таких пользователей?
Подскажите, как это сделать. 
И можете посоветовать какие-нибудь книги по защите сайта от различных атак(dos, ddos, sql иньекции и так далее)
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: С динамическими ip замучаете бороться.